# Reading arbitrary NFC card

Tags: android, nfc

I have the source code an NFC reader for Android which supports a few different NFC cards. And I happen to have a NFC card which isn't supported by it.

What do I need to know to add support for it? Should I get the information of the format or something of that card from the manufacturer of the card on their website?

Or is there any more general, universal way **which doesn't require contacting me the manufacturer** or going to their website?

Comment: Download an NFC reader with a good rating from Google Play. Does it read it? What does it say? Then, look it up on the web site of the manufacturer. The card should have a brandname and a model name. If it's part of the NFC spec, it should have a type number as well.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, that's what I've done and that's what my question is about.

Comment: Did you use an NFC reader made by NFC labs? or made by NXP? If not, go on google play, and try one of those. Also, you didn't tell us what was written on that card. Is there anything written on that card? Where did you get it?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, how does that matter which one I'm using? The question is basically how to add a support of a new card? None of those readers support my new card, re-read my question. They say "unsupported card".

Comment: I read it. This is what it says: "I have the source code an NFC reader for Android which supports a few different NFC cards."

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, "And I happen to have a NFC card which isn't supported by it. " (or by them)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93038/discussion-between-stephan-branczyk-and-jawanam).

Comment: Without more information about the card you want to support there is no answer possible. You should post the info that "NFX TagInfo" gives you about the card.

Comment: @AlexS, that's not a question about my particular card, it's a general question about any NFC card.

Answer (score 0):

In general, your application should declare a subset of technologies, which are supported by NFC tag, you want to read. Android dispatches NFC tags in this order (read [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html) to learn more):

- [ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED)
- [ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED)
- [ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED)

You can register your application for **ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED** and declare every technology in separated resource (you can learn more about technologies [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/TagTechnology.html)). Your app should declare a subset of technologies returned by [NFC tag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/Tag.html) when calling [getTechList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/Tag.html#getTechList%28%29).

After all, follow specified technology to read its data.